# Как 100% удалить вирус?

Tags: вирусы, антивирус

Сегодня у меня произошла такая ситуация:
я сидел общялся с людьми в discord и тут мой курсор начинает трясти этот курсор не перемещался а телепортировался в нужные точки он так закрыл мне все окна и начинал творить хаос я быстро выключил ноутбук и включил заново как только включил сразу же отключил wi fi и начал проверку спомощю антивируса антивирус нашел 20 угроз, все эти угрозы я удалил но если вирус хорошо закриптовали антивирус его врятли найдет, у меня windows 10, делал проверку с помощю антивируса malwarbytes. Как окончательно удалить все вирусы?

Answer (score 4):

> скажите сто процентно удалить вирус со своего ноутбука

как только узнаете этот метод, любая антивирусная компания вас оторвет с руками

> начал проверку спомощю антивируса антивирус нашел 20 угроз, все эти угрозы я удалил но если вирус хорошо закриптовали антивирус его врятли найдет,

если у вас изначально был установлен антивирус, почему он не находил угрозы? или вы на предупреждение антивируса клали?

от антивируса в ситуации, когда вредоносная программа устанавливается РАНЬШЕ антивируса на компьютер может спрятаться только Rootkit, не очень и частый случай, так что если антивирусом пролечили - скорее всего он все вылечил

просто установите антивирус и регулярно обновляйте базы и будет вам счастье

ну и после установки антивируса выставить защиту на максимум, глубину поиска на максимум, время поиска на максимум, проверку архивов и т.д. и еще раз проверить ВЕСЬ компьютер (т.е. ВСЕ жесткие диски, флешки и т.д.)

P.S.

ну если вам совсем уж страшно, то тогда форматируйте диск и устанавливайте с флешки новую ОС :)

Comment: у меня была выключена защита в режиме реального времени поетому он не находил их

Comment: ну поздравляю :) сейчас не 80е годы, чтобы раз в неделю проверку компьютера запускать, сейчас все как раз в реальном времени должно проверяться, а также не только файловый антивирус, но и почтовый, браузерный, соцсетевой и т.п. (обычно это все входит в набор антивирусных продуктов, надо только все включить ну или не выключать)

Comment: у меня в антивирусе не была включена защита в реальном времени потому что я сам немного занимаюсь вирусами, и не очень круто когда я только что скомпелировал свой python код в exe файл а антивирус его сразу же удаляет

Comment: тем болие что антивирусы часто находят вирусы там где их нету

Comment: посмотрите отчеты - независимого тестирования - ложные срабатывания в районе 1-% (зачастую 0.1%) и это уж точно лучше ваших найденных `20 угроз`

Answer (score 2):

Переустанови Windows, это самое разумное решение

Comment: у меня на компютере слишком много важных данных

Comment: @Sheud_z Касперский вроде неплох.

Comment: @Sheud_z ну так я предлагаю переустановить Windows, а не удалять важные данные

Comment: @Sheud_z 100% гарантии никакой антивирус не даст. Могу только порекомендовать Panda Dome, есть бесплатная версия, запусти полную проверку, а еще попробуй встроенный в Windows антивирус, он тоже очень хороший (только перед этим зайди в обновления Windows и обнови все компоненты, чтобы обновить вирусную базу данных)

Comment: ладно попробую через windows defender

Comment: да любой антивирус из первой десятки дает 99% обнаружения, @Sheud_z, если у вас много важных данных, что же вы на безопасность этих данных клали то? раз у вас только после ручной проверки начало что-то обнаруживаться?

Answer (score -1):

Надо пользоваться любым известным антивирусом. Malwarbytes - темная лошадка. О нем не особо публикуют информацию серьезные специализированные издания/сайты. Ничего не известно о том, проверяли ли его серьезные независимые лаборатории.

Если есть подозрение на вирус, переустановка операционной системы. И поставить любой антивирус из хорошо известных. Можно взять и бесплатный.
Выбрать можно здесь: https://pcask.ru/software/kakoj-antivirus-luchshe/

Comment: Тем временем Kasperky, MacAfee, Avast и Защитник Windows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4FxY.jpg